# Autohotkey script to bookmark to a specific folder

Tags: autohotkey

I'm using Firefox and I was looking for an autohotkey script which would enable me to skip the whole series of clicks when I bookmark a page in a specific folder and replace it with a single keyboard shortcut.

Although I've read forum threads on Autohotkey forum and here I still don't know how to make a working script that would reduce bookmarking a page to hitting a keyboard shortcut and the initial letter of the folder where I want to store that page. Using KeyWait command I've made it work for a single folder and don't know how to make it work for any letter or a number that I could possibly use as a name for a bookmark folder. Say I have a folder named XXXX, this script does send the webpage to the XXXX folder after hitting the assigned shortcut and the letter x (MouseClick command is needed to focus the window with folder in the Bookmark Dialog pane):

```
!+^w::
Send,^d
Sleep,400
MouseClick,Left,864,304
Sleep,400
KeyWait, x ,D    
Sleep, 400
Send,^{Enter}
return
```

I don't know how to make this script work for any letter or number, not only for a single one. Also a big problem with this script is that it blocks the keyboard until I hit X key. If I have that page bookmarked already, hitting escape to remove the bookmark pane will block the keyboard and I can unblock it only if I rerun the autohotkey script.

I've also tried using Input command as the contributors the Autohotkey forum pages suggested, but it didn't work either, because I don't understand how the Input command works. I did make it work for a single letter as the above script with KeyWait, but that's the best I could do. This script also blocks the keyboard until the letter is hit:

```
!+^w::
Send,^d
MouseClick,Left,864,304
Sleep,400
Input, Character, L1
If Character = t
Send, t
Sleep,400
Send,^{Enter}
return
```

Hope someone can help me with this, it would be convenient simplifying the bookmarking process in Firefox this way.

Comment: your second approach looks good to me ...? try to replace `if character = t` / `send, t` with a simple `send %character%`. If you want `Input` not to block the sent keys, use the `V` option (see ahkscript documentation -> input)

Comment: Hi Blauhirn, thank you for the answer. Does the Input command work like KeyWait? I want the script to carry out the rest of the code after waiting for the input of a character. Confirming a bookmark in the Bookmark Dialog window is done by Ctrl+Enter, and I want to avoid that shortcut by having a script that will automate it for me.

Comment: yes, `input` "pauses" the script like `keyWait`. You stated `L1`, so after the first key press, it will continue instantly. The typed letter will be saved into `Character`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a nice idea. This will open the add bookmark dialog and navigate you into the folder selection part and expand all folders. 
All you need to do is enter the folders name (or a part of it) and it will get selected automatically. When you're done, just hit enter.

```
!+^w::                      ;Hotkey: Ctrl+Alt+Shift+w
    Send, ^d                ;send Ctrl+d to open the add-bookmark dialog
    Sleep, 500              ;wait for the dialog to open
    Send, {Tab}{Tab}{Enter} ;navigate into the folder selection
    Sleep, 300              ;wait to make sure we are there
    Send,{Home}             ;select the first item in the list
                            ;The following line should expand all the folders so that you can just type the folders name to search for it
    Loop, 100 {             ;Increase the number if it doesn't expand all folders
        SendInput, {Right}{Down} ;expand folders
    }
    Send, {Home}            ;navigate to the first item in the list again
    Input, L, V L1 T2       ;wait until you start typing a folder name (if you just wait 2 seconds, the bookmark won't be created)
    If (ErrorLevel =  "Timeout") {
        Send, {Tab 5}       ;press tab 5 times to navigate to the cancel button
        Send, {Enter}       ;cancel the bookmark
        Return              ;end of the hotkey
    }
    Loop {                  ;wait until you haven't typed a new letter for 0.4 seconds
        Input, L, V L1 T0.4
        If (ErrorLevel =  "Timeout")
            Break
    }
    Send, {Tab 4}           ;press tab 4 times to navigate to the enter button
    Send, {Enter}           ;save the bookmark
Return
```

Comment: Hi Forivin thank you for the help! I want to get rid of "Enter". I get the folders window focused with the MouseClick command all I need to do is to type the letter and hit Enter. I don't need KeyWait or Input for that. I've already reduced bookmarking to a single shortcut, a single letter and hitting Enter. It may sound as unnecessary but I do a lot of bookmarking and I want to make it as short work as possible which means that I'd like to avoid hitting Enter too, which is why I need KeyWait or Input function, to automate this one last step of confirming the letter I typed in.

Comment: Okay, but that means that every folder has to start with a different letter. Do you really want that?

Comment: @RejlanGivens I just had an idea and edited the script. The script will now wait until you have stopped typing the folder name for 0.4 seconds then it will save the bookmark for you automatically. It works really great for me, what do you think?

Comment: Works like a charm thank you so much Forivin! I don't have a problem with the blocked keyboard either, when I don't confirm the bookmark, although the shortcut in such case won't work until the keyboard is used again, which really isn't a problem at all. (for example the bookmark I was going to save is already in my bookmarks and I hit escape or just click the mouse on another page, in that case the shortcut won't work if I wanted to bookmark that other page, until I activate keyboard again, start typing whatever, which for some reason re-enables the shortcut again). Thank you a lot again!

Comment: Once I have 15 reputation the forum requires for voting here, I'll upvote your script, as an info to the other people who might find this feature useful as I do.

Comment: I edited the script again, now if you just wait 2 seconds without typing, the bookmark creation will be canceled. I think you can click the accept button on the answer. ;)

Comment: Now it works perfectly Forivin :) This way of bookmarking is a real time saver to me thank you again. I've tried upvoting the answer, I get an information that I'll able to do that when I have 15 reputation. Have a nice day Forivin!

Comment: Accepting is not the same as upvoting, I was talking about the check mark next to the answer. You should click it if you think the answer solved your problems.

Answer (score 0):

My variant.
Press f1 to create bookmark in folder test1.
Press f2 to create bookmark in folder test2.

```
SetBatchLines, -1
Folders := {F1: "test1", F2: "test2"}
#IfWinActive, ahk_class MozillaWindowClass
F1::
F2::
Folder := Folders[A_ThisHotkey]
Send, ^d
AccFirefox := Acc_ObjectFromWindow(WinExist("ahk_class MozillaWindowClass"))
AccElem := SearchElement(AccFirefox, ROLE_SYSTEM_LISTITEM := 0x22, Folder, "")
AccElem.accDoDefaultAction(0)
sleep 100
Send {Enter}
msgbox done
return
#IfWinActive

SearchElement(ParentElement, params*)
{
   found := 1
   for k, v in params  {
      (k = 1 && ParentElement.accRole(0) != v && found := "")
      (k = 2 && ParentElement.accName(0) != v && found := "")
      (k = 3 && ParentElement.accValue(0) != v && found := "")
   }
   if found
      Return ParentElement

   for k, v in Acc_Children(ParentElement)
      if obj := SearchElement(v, params*)
         Return obj
}

Acc_Init()
{
    Static  h
    If Not  h
        h:=DllCall("LoadLibrary","Str","oleacc","Ptr")
}

Acc_ObjectFromWindow(hWnd, idObject = 0)
{
    Acc_Init()
    If  DllCall("oleacc\AccessibleObjectFromWindow", "Ptr", hWnd, "UInt", idObject&=0xFFFFFFFF, "Ptr", -VarSetCapacity(IID,16)+NumPut(idObject==0xFFFFFFF0?0x46000000000000C0:0x719B3800AA000C81,NumPut(idObject==0xFFFFFFF0?0x0000000000020400:0x11CF3C3D618736E0,IID,"Int64"),"Int64"), "Ptr*", pacc)=0
    Return  ComObjEnwrap(9,pacc,1)
}

Acc_Query(Acc) { ; thanks Lexikos - www.autohotkey.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=81731&p=509530#509530
    try return ComObj(9, ComObjQuery(Acc,"{618736e0-3c3d-11cf-810c-00aa00389b71}"), 1)
}

Acc_Error(p="") {
    static setting:=0
    return p=""?setting:setting:=p
}

Acc_Children(Acc) {
    if ComObjType(Acc,"Name") != "IAccessible"
        ErrorLevel := "Invalid IAccessible Object"
    else {
        Acc_Init(), cChildren:=Acc.accChildCount, Children:=[]
        if DllCall("oleacc\AccessibleChildren", "Ptr",ComObjValue(Acc), "Int",0, "Int",cChildren, "Ptr",VarSetCapacity(varChildren,cChildren*(8+2*A_PtrSize),0)*0+&varChildren, "Int*",cChildren)=0 {
            Loop %cChildren%
                i:=(A_Index-1)*(A_PtrSize*2+8)+8, child:=NumGet(varChildren,i), Children.Insert(NumGet(varChildren,i-8)=9?Acc_Query(child):child), NumGet(varChildren,i-8)=9?ObjRelease(child):
            return Children.MaxIndex()?Children:
        } else
            ErrorLevel := "AccessibleChildren DllCall Failed"
    }
    if Acc_Error()
        throw Exception(ErrorLevel,-1)
}
```

Comment: Hi Malcev thank you! I've tried it and it doesn't place the bookmark in the test1 or test2 folder I've created in both Bookmarks Menu and Bookmarks Toolbar. It saves the page in Bookmarks menu directly. The "done" dialog is not necessary to me, and I don't understand how adding shortcuts for folders works. Forivin's solution allows typing in either the initial letter of the folder or the whole name, so any folder in any bookmark location is easily assigned a bookmark. It also resolves the problem of blocking the script when I decide not to bookmark the page because it's already bookmarked.

Comment: Try to increase sleep. from sleep 100 to sleep 200 or 300. Shorcut for folders is not necessary. Script searches for exact folder name. But if You have several folders with the same name - the script saves in folder which finds at first.

Comment: No, still doesn't work for me malcev, sorry. I don't get the folder window opened when I run the script so I can't type in the name of the folder I want to store the bookmark to.